# Guardar valores em elementos Javascript - Boas práticas

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber se é uma boa prática guardar valores diretamente nos elementos para não precisar calcular novamente. Por exemplo:

```
function scrollfunc(e){
    var el = e.currentTarget;
    var deltaY = (el.deltaY !== undefined)? (el.deltaY + e.y) : e.y;

    el.style.transform = 'translateY(' + deltaY + 'px)';
    el.deltaY = deltaY;
}

document.getElementById('#scrollElement').addEventListener(scrollfunc);
```

Answer (score -3):

Embora seja possível armazenar informações diretamente nos elementos do DOM, como no exemplo que você colocou, geralmente não é considerado uma boa prática. Isso principalmente por dois motivos :

1-) Problemas de desempenho : O motivo de causar problemas de desempenho é que acessar o DOM é mais lento que acessar um objeto direto na memória.

2-) Pode dificultar a manutenção do código : Colocar toda a sua estrutura de forma "flat" no elemento pode causar problemas de legibilidade. Não tem separação de responsabilidade. Colocar todas as informações nos elementos é o equivalente a declarar as variáveis de forma global e com todos os problemas que isto pode causar.

Solução:

Ao invés disso, você pode criar um objeto javascript que mapeias o seu elemento no DOM e guarde as informações necessárias e tenha a responsabilidade adequada.